# Structure direct assignment error in C++ gcc with conversion

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a small code sample like this:

```
enum class X       
{
   A,         
   B      
};

struct Y
{
    X x = X::A;
};

struct S
{
    Y unit[2] = {};
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s = {};
}
```

This code fails to compile in gcc 12.3 and 13.2 with `-std=c++17`, but it compiles with `-std=c++11`. It also compiles in clang with `-std=c++17`. I don't think this code should be incorrect. It is somehow should be a normal direct assignment in form (2) here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment

Is it possible that this is a bug in gcc?

**Update:** This is gcc error:

```
<source>:20:10: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'S' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')
   20 |     s = {};
      |          ^
<source>:13:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr S& S::operator=(const S&)'
   13 | struct S
      |        ^
<source>:13:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const S&'
<source>:13:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr S& S::operator=(S&&)'
<source>:13:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'S&&'
```

from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6hxW9cKrb).

Comment: it would be much easier if you provided the GCC error text. Also try replace it with 'S s {}' to avoid copying.

Comment: @folibis added error. In addition, this is just example. That assignment is for when you want to reinitialize your variable, so I will not be able to use `S s{}`.

Comment: Better godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/ohd6vcMrh

Comment: Please note that while [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) has a specific meaning in the C++ language, what you called "reinitialize" is an assignment to an already declared variable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the code does compile with c++11. It is reproducible on my side.

CppReference [Struct Initialization Page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) mentions that particular initialization illegal until C23:

> In C, the braced list of initializers cannot be empty (note that C++ allows empty lists, and also note that a struct in C cannot be empty):
> (until C23)
>
> The initializer list can be empty in C as in C++:
> (since C23)
>
> ```cpp
> struct {int n;} s = {0}; // OK
> struct {int n;} s = {}; // Error until C23: initializer-list cannot be empty
>                         // OK since C23: s.n is initialized to 0
> struct {} s = {}; // Error: struct cannot be empty
> ```

The correct way to initialize it empty should be `s = {{}}`

Comment: This answer isn’t obviously related to the question, since your answer only concerns *initialisation*, whereas the question is about *assignment*. These are different operations, governed by different rules.

Comment: Why referring to `C`? `enum class` make this C++ specific. Also flag `-pedantic` which should disable C extensions do not impact [issue in question](https://godbolt.org/z/ohd6vcMrh).

Comment: This answer is not related. My question is exactly about assignment. I mean form (2) of direct assignment in here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment